# How is the severity/priority of a vulnerability in the Ubuntu CVE tracker determined?

Tags: security

For example, [CVE-2017-14491](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-14491.html) has a priority level of "high".

Is there any formal method to determine the priority of this vulnerability (unique to Canonical)? Or is this priority based on the disclosure of other vendors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Ubuntu Security Team's wiki page on Bug Triage](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/BugTriage) says that priority levels are described in [ubuntu-cve-tracker's README](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/ubuntu-cve-tracker/master/view/head:/README#L191), where you can see this:

> ### Ubuntu Priorities
>
> These are very similar to the Debian priorities, but with some
>   differences. Priorities can be roughly mapped as:
>
> **negligible**  Something that is technically a security problem, but
>   is        only theoretical in nature, requires a very special         situation,
>   has almost no install base, or does no real       damage.  These tend not
>   to get backport from upstreams,       and will likely not be included in
>   security updates unless       there is an easy fix and some other issue
>   causes an update.
>
> **low**     Something that is a security problem, but is hard to
>         exploit due to environment, requires a user-assisted        attack, a
>   small install base, or does very little damage.       These tend to be
>   included in security updates only when        higher priority issues
>   require an update, or if many         low priority issues have built up.
>
> **medium**  Something is a real security problem, and is exploitable
>         for many people.  Includes network daemon denial of service 
>         attacks, cross-site scripting, and gaining user privileges.
>         Updates should be made soon for this priority of issue.
>
> **high**        A real problem, exploitable for many people in a default
>         installation.  Includes serious remote denial of services,      local
>   root privilege escalations, or data loss.
>
> **critical**    A world-burning problem, exploitable for nearly all
>   people        in a default installation of Ubuntu.  Includes remote root
>                   privilege escalations, or massive data loss.

CVE-2017-14491 has high priority because dnsmasq is installed by default and the bug allows both denial-of-service and code execution remotely and is not particularly hard to exploit.

Comment: I think the fact that there exist multiple priority/severity standard such as Redhat's and NVD's are very confusing and potentially misleading for some of the security administrators