# Incorrect CVE severity in OVAL content

Tags: security

I am looking at https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/oval/com.ubuntu.trusty.cve.oval.xml

Here, for CVE-2017-5638, the severity is set to Medium - 
https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2017/CVE-2017-5638.html

This is incorrect. According to NVD, the severity should be High.

Is this a typo or is there a reason why it is set to Medium even though NVD has marked it High?

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/q/963803/158442

Answer (score 4):

CVE tracker doesn't have *severity*.  It has ***priority***, and is set to what the Security team thinks the priority is for how important the issue is to fix.

This is detailed in the [Ubuntu CVE tracker README file](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/ubuntu-cve-tracker/master/view/head:/README#L191), which you really should consider reading because it gives better insights here.

Marc Deslauriers on IRC replied in my proxy inquiry on this:

> mdeslaur> we don't have severity, we have "priority" which is based on how we prioritize work, not on the impact of the security issue
>
> mdeslaur> also, the package in that specific question is in universe, where most of the time the priority just defaults to "medium" unless someone contributes something better

With regards to the package in question, though, it's in Universe, and "Medium" is usually the default for those I believe.

Comment: I've updated the CVE priority to 'untriaged' which means that we haven't fully considered the priority of the issue. In this specific case, it is because Ubuntu is not affected and the package in question is in universe.

Comment: Perhaps then you are doing it wrong.
```
<advisory>
                    <severity>Medium</severity>
                     <public_date>2017-03-10</public_date>
                    <discovered_by>Nike Zheng</discovered_by>
</advisory>
```
You are using severity tag which actually means severity. Either you should stop populating it or pull the criticality from NVD. 

By the way, an advisory should have criticality aspect to it. Why omitting is a good idea? Security advisory loses its meaning without this criticality information.

Comment: By the way, CVE-2017-5638 is the one exploited for Equifax. Not sure why security team thought it is medium in the first place? So, to take things to the conclusion, does it mean the oval security content provided by Ubuntu comes with no security warranty or legitimacy? It just sits there - if someone can derive any value out of it, fine else never mind?

Comment: @praving5 - As explained by Thomas Ward, you are confusing the "severity" of the security exploit with the "priority" assigned by the security team. It defaults to "medium" priority. Probably a reasonable default as all security bugs are already highest priority anyways , so medium withing the high priority of security bugs seems to be a reasonable default. This is explained in detail in the link you were given - http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/ubuntu-cve-tracker/master/view/head:/README#L191 .

Comment: @praving5 - Medium is the priority due to the package location in universe, and thus not part of the ubuntu core. You also missed "Ubuntu is not affected " . So when you review the scenario, although equifax was / is a serious problem , Ubuntu is not affected, so the security team pirotitized the bug appropriately. Apparently Equifax or users of Equifax services should consider using Ubuntu more =)

Comment: @praving5 I'm certain the severity of the issue is taken into account, but consider that a high severity issue in a non-Main package is going to be prioritized in favor of a high severity issue in a main package (say, nginx or Apache) first.  Priority therefore does not directly equate to *severity*, though I believe it has *some* influence.